# TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined - angularjs localforage

Tags: angularjs, localforage

I am tryng the basic example of angular localforage from this [link](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage)

but i got below error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
>       at new LocalForageInstance (angular-localForage.js:51)
>       at $get (angular-localForage.js:460)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4203)
>       at angular.js:4021
>       at getService (angular.js:4162)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4194)
>       at angular.js:6524
>       at forEach (angular.js:323)
>       at Object. (angular.js:6522)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4203)

i have configured with the below code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['LocalForageModule']).config(['$localForageProvider', function($localForageProvider) {
    $localForageProvider.config({
        name: 'myApp' // name of the database and prefix for your data
    });
}]);
```

I am newbie to angularjs and trying to use local storage. I found localForage has lots of feature. please help me fix this.

Comment: can you provide your html ?

Comment: Did you include your localForage.js in your index? And, If you want a suggestion, separate **dependency injection** from that **localForageProvider**. Put dependency injection in a separated file, same thing for your localForage configuration.